# Iterative recurrence... Iteration method

Tags: algorithm, methods, recursion, iteration

I have tried to solve the following recurrence relation using Iteration method,

```
T(1) = 8  
T(n) = 3T(n-1) - 15
```

Iterations:

**i=1**

```
T(n) = 3(3T(n-2) - 15) -15
```

**i=2**

```
3(3(3T(n-3) - 15) -15) - 15
```

**i=3**

```
 3(3(3(3T(n-4) - 15) -15) - 15) - 15
```

**i=4**

```
3(3(3(3(3T(n-5) - 15) -15) - 15) - 15) - 15
```

From the iteration pattern I found that
**T(n) = 3<sup>(i+1)</sup> * T(n-(i+1)) - 15**

Now I need to find the summation for this recurrence relation and obtain the closed form. I'm just not sure how to proceed.

Can someone guide me to solving this problem?

Comment: The [Mathematics Stack Exchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/?as=1) may be a better place for this.

Comment: Alright thanks Kevin, ill try asking there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Recurrence relation is,

```
T(n) = 3T(n-1) - 15                        ------ 1

T(n-1) = 3T(n-2) - 15                      ------ 2

1-2 ->  T(n) - T(n-1) = 3T(n-1) - 3T(n-2)  ------ 3

T(n) - 4T(n-1)  + 3T(n-2) = 0              ------ 4
```

The corresponding characteristic equation is,

**x<sup>2</sup> -4x + 3 = 0**

x = 3 and x = 1 are the solutions,

There for the general solution is,

**T(n) = a 1<sup>n</sup> + b 3<sup>n</sup>**

Which implies **T(n) = a + b 3<sup>n</sup>**

We have T(1) = 8,

There for `a + 3b = 8   ---- 5`

T(2) = 9,

There for `a + 9b = 9   ---- 6`

solving 5 & 6, we get a = 15/2 and b = 1/6.

Thus the general solution is, **T(n) = (1/6) 3<sup>n</sup> + 15/2**.